# Combine similar resource routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have the follow set of collection routes in my Rails 4 app:

```
resources :stats do
  collection do
    match 'mrr', via: [:get, :post]
    match 'upgrades', via: [:get, :post]
    match 'arpu', via: [:get, :post]
    match 'arr', via: [:get, :post]
    match 'ltv', via: [:get, :post]
  end
end
```

There will be at least another dozen or so of those `match` lines.

Is there a way to condense that so I don't keep repeating (especially the `via` method options)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's perfectly readable but you could do:

```
resources :stats do
  collection do
    %w(mrr upgrades arpu arr ltv).each do |stat| 
      match stat, via: [:get, :post]
    end
  end
end
```